# How to efficiently fill missing values in columns with pairwise dependency in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, large-data

I have a dataset where I have two types of IDs per observation, i.e. there's a pairwise dependency between the IDs. However, sometimes one of the IDs might be missing from the row. The data looks like this:

```
      id_x      id_y
1   user_1      user_a
2     ''        user_b
3     ''        user_b
4   user_3      user_c
5   user_2      user_b
6   user_3        ''
```

Where `''` is the empty string and not `np.NaN` . The data rows are not ordered (i.e., observations of `user_1` may be interspersed).
In the example above, we would like to fill `id_x` in rows 2 and 3, with `user_2` since we see that this is the correct mapping for `user_2` seen in row 5. At the same time, we would like to fill `id_y` in row 6 with 'user_c' since that's the correct mapping seen in row 4.

One solution is to iterate over all unique users, slice the dataframe, and backfill.

```
for user in list(id_y.unique()):
    df[df.id_y==user]['id_x'].replace('',np.NaN).bfill(axis='rows')
```

Another solution is to create a dictionary with all the mappings between pairs and then do an apply function. In this case, we will basically be doing a dictionary lookup for each missing value.

I'm working with pretty big dataframes so I'm wondering whether there's a more efficient solution than the above two methods.

Comment: Is the information truly redundant? Do you handle cases where both columns are empty? There is a conflict between existing mappings? A missing value does not have a mapping elsewhere?

Comment: I'm confused. Your sample code doesn't do anything.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, the information is redundant because they are observations of users across time. For cases with empty columns we simply have to disregard the rows since there's no way to retrieve the ID. A missing value with no mapping is also possible, depending on which ID it is, I might be able to use it. Lastly, there's another issue that I didn't present above for simplicity, but it's possible that some mappings have collisions.

Comment: @user17242583 you are correct, there was a typo. The core idea is to iteratively select slices of the dataframe by using one of the user ID columns. This would ensure that all the selected rows belong to the same user ID. Thus, when using backfill you can guarantee that you are correctly backfilling